# Rails dev server that allows multiple requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to be able to make a request to a ruby method on a rails app after calling a long-running request that would run in parallel to the request. I know that using a background processing gem would make this possible, however is there a dev server that handles more than one request?

Comment: What do you mean? What are you using that doesn't?

Comment: I'm guessing that he's referring to Webbrick and how it only processes one request at a time. He has a function that's going for quite a while and wants to be able to serve other pages while that function is processing.

Comment: Try `thin` instead: https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/

Comment: If you want multi-threaded backend you can try [Puma](https://github.com/puma/puma)